# Can we assign JavaScript variable value to EJS variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to put a JS variable value in an EJS variable which is in the same page.

```
<script>
    var  i = 22;
    document.getElementById('abcd').innerHTML = i;
    <% ejsVar %> = i;
</script>
```

Comment: So, EJS will run on the server BEFORE the page is delivered to the browser.  Your  Javascript inside that `<script>` tag will run in the browser after the `<% ejsVar %>` has already been filled in with something by the server.  So, it seems unlikely this will do what you want.  But, for anyone to help you, you will need to describe what you're trying to accomplish.  Questions here should describe your real problem, not just an issue you have with the way you're trying to code it.

Comment: Yes, <script> tag will run in the browser after the <% ejsVar %> has already been filled in with something by the server.

Comment: Still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am already using `<% ejsVar %>` in my code. I have a onclick function, when called, js variable value should be assigned to that ejs variable. @jfriend00

Comment: You don't seem to understand that EJS is already long since processed on the server before the page gets to the browser and before any onclick can be processed.  There is no EJS in the browser.  Define your own Javascript variable in your `<script>` tag and assign to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, as EJS templates are evaluated *before* the page is sent to the client. To represent simply the process, it goes like this:

Server: run Node.js -> evaluate your script -> runs EJS (which evaluates the templates) -> send to the browser -> Client: evaluate the HTML and run the JavaScript code

What is possible is to assign a value to an EJS variable on the server side, by giving a value to the renderer object:

```
let ejs = require('ejs');
let scope = {};

// Assign a value to an EJS variable
scope.ejsVar = "Hello world!";

// Render the template using the scope
let html = ejs.render('Var: <%= ejsVar %>', scope); // "Var: Hello world!";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your variable value to request body obj from client
2. Call a post request to your server by passing request body from client
3. extract your value from req.body and assign it to your ejs variable in your server
4. You can use npm body-parser to extract it in your server, https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser